# Java switch case single and non-single command inputs

Tags: java

These are all possible commands I want to accept.

> ```
> Q
> H
> A
> D
> L <Color> <Drawer>
> M <Drawer1> <Drawer2>
> ```

I have this switch case. **What is the best method to error check the input/ where is the best place to scan for potential non-single letter commands like 'L' or 'M' commands?** I would like to have only one default case in the code, to avoid copy-pasting the error message in more than one place. Also, I'm worried about commands like `Q zzzzz` being accepted, since I am only calling `reader.next()` which reads until the next whitespace. Should I be using `reader.nextline()` instead?

```
String input = reader.next();

 switch (input.toUpperCase())
        {
            case "Q": //Quit:
                //.....
                break;

            case "H": //Help:
                //.....
                break;

            case "A": //About:
                //.....
                break;

            case "D": //Draw:
                //.....
                break;

            case "L": //Lay:
                //prompt for more input here? 
                //if so, and the input is wrong, how to jump to default?
                //.....
                break;

            case "M": //Move:
                //same issue as 'L'
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("\nYour command was not recognized.  Type H for help.");
        }//end switch()
```

I originally thought to scan three times before the switch case (2 of them might be empty if user chooses a single-letter command).

I can code a solution, but it would be a very ugly one. I am just a beginner programmer trying to write things elegantly.

Comment: this code won't work even if you type "L red drawer1", because case "L" wouldn't catch it

Comment: Your right, this isn't working code. Updated OP to bold the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
String input = reader.nextLine();

char c = input.charAt(0);

if ( (c != 'M' && c != 'L') && input.length() > 1)
   // throw some error message

switch(c)
...
 case "L": //Lay:
            // parse the rest of input here
            break;
```

Comment: This fixes 'Azzz', but wouldn't this allow for input like 'A zzz' ? because input.length() always returns 1

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated my answer to `nextLine()`.

Comment: This solution works, but I would like to only print an error message one time, once in the 'if', and once in the switch()

Comment: Then just enhance the if-statement to check if `c` is in the allowed range of characters...

Answer (score 1):

Assume we enter the command L red hi (for some reason if i put text inside <> it disappears, even with quotes "")

You can use something like this in the default case:

```
input.matches("^[L-M] <\\w*> <\\w*>$")
```

This will check for the right formatting. Then you can continue checking with:

```
input.substring(3, 6).equals("Red")
```

And finally:

```
input.substring(9, 11).equals("Hi")
```

Note that the first number in the substring command is the first letter of the command (right after '<') and the second number is the closing '>'. 'L' is 0, making 'R' 3, and the first '>' 6.

The complete code for this situation is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the letter: ");
    String input = reader.nextLine();

     switch (input.toUpperCase())
            {
                case "Q": //Quit:
                    //.....
                    break;

                case "H": //Help:
                    //.....
                    break;

                case "A": //About:
                    //.....
                    break;

                case "D": //Draw:
                    //.....
                    break;

                default:
                    if(input.matches("^L <\\w*> <\\w*>$")){
                        // Use the below if-else statements for all L <text> commands
                        if (input.substring(3, 6).equals("Red")){
                            if (input.substring(9, 11).equals("Hi")){
                                // Do stuff
                                /* Note: the first number is counting from 0 to the first letter
                                 * of the sub-command (H) in the following:
                                 * L <Red> <Hi>
                                 * It comes out as 9
                                 * The second number (11) is the closing sign thing (>)
                                 * You will need to modify these according to your commands
                                 */
                            }
                            // Use else-if statements for different secondary commands
                            else
                                System.out.println("\nYour command was not recognized.  Type H for help.");
                                // You can replace this error message with a boolean value, or a method
                                // To avoid the message appearing in the code more than once.
                        }
                        // Use else-if statements for different commands
                        else // Final else command
                            System.out.println("\nYour command was not recognized.  Type H for help.");                     
                    }
                    // After the different commands, the next else-if is to check for
                    // M <Stuff> <Stuff>

            }//end switch()

}
```

Hope this helps!